# Is there a free way to activate SCL RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, scl

I wish to use the software collection of RHEL 7, but it seems theres is not free way to do that. Anyone knows ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [register as a developer](http://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/get-started/) to download the [SCL](http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/)

Comment: But if I have already a subscription as server user ?

Answer (score 2):

then register your installation using the `sudo subscription-manager register --username YOUR_USER --password YOUR_PASS`. 
After you should be able to enable SCL like it's described here: softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php70/ - `sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`